# How to get the Number of the item in a List in Flutter in a Text Widget

Tags: flutter

I have a list from a Model Class which generate a list:

```
List<User> user = [
  currentUser,
  stefano,
  roberta,
  sabrina,
  carmine,
  paolo,
  calogero,
  ernesto,
  oreste,
];
```

each item of this list has his own data in this case I have 8 users in this list and I would the Number 8 appears in a TextWidget in Flutter but I can achieve that even useing int.parse.
at the moment I import the Class:

```
  final Consultant consultant;
  final User user;
  final Message message;

  const DashBoardScreen({Key key, this.consultant, this.user, this.message}) : super(key: key);
```

and other list and I am trying into a tezxt widget to get the number with:

```
Text(int.parse(user.length))
```

but unsuccesfully.

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: I can't use lenght and: Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
                               int.parse(user.length),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly import the list if you are using Navigator, another thing make sure you have passed the list/class correctly.

You are getting error because Text widget needs a String not int so use a string interpolation or just add .toString at the end.

And change your code to this

```
Text(${widget.user.length}), // or to this Text(widget.user.length.toString()),
```

Comment: I dont import the list via navigator because this is a Display widget where I display the number of the item in the list .

Comment: Ok did you try the code I gave? By adding widget before user

Comment: the problem was that it needs string interpolation with ${user.lenght} I solved.

Comment: or just add .toString() at the end. It's always a solution when 'something' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.